# How to handle "This element is not interactable through selenium(automation) as it is not visible in UI." in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-java

I'm trying to close the modal that pops up when opening a netbanking website. But I'm unable to identify the modal. Selectors hub shows the above error.

```html
<div class="popup" id="popup" style="display": block;" xpath="1">
<div class="close-btn" data-bind="click:$component.closePopup" style="" xpath="1">x</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question. It's also worth taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: Here is a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) which may also help you to ask a quality question.

Comment: Take a look at the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) guide to understand why your HTML fragment was not visible. You can [edit] the question to see why it is visible now.

Comment: Someone may be able to provide an answer, but the question is still missing important information needed to help make the problem clear and reproducible ([mre]). Also, this type of question [has been asked](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+selenium+modal+popup&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+selenium+modal+popup) before. Have you researched this topic? If so, what were your findings?